# Parsing JSON feed to webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to pull data (title, author, etc) from this json file:
http://www.nba.com/grizzlies/api/v1/json

How would I go about this in Javascript/jQuery?
I can't seem to be able to.

Comment: that url is not CORS enabled. Also when asking about `how` you need to post code you have tried ... this isn't a code writing service...people help you with code you write

Comment: [It is JSONP](http://www.nba.com/grizzlies/api/v1/json?callback=parsejson) enabled tho.

Comment: i'll look into JSONP, but I've tried something from this tutorial: http://beautifulbeta.wikidot.com/json-feeds

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.nba.com/grizzlies/api/v1/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $.each(value, function (idx, val) {
                console.log(val.author);


            })


        })

    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
});
```

If you want to try demo below.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpzh5wfe/3/)

Comment: thank you, this is a good start.

Comment: glad it helped happy coding